# How to increase the favorites limit by token, in rtweet in R?

Tags: r, rtweet

I'm using the rtweet package from R.I would like to have a list of all the favorites for a Twitter account, but the limit for returning favorites per token is 3000.

```
Favs<-get_favorites("user",n=33000)
```

Error returning:

```
Warning message:
n exceeds max favs returned per token. Setting n to 3000...
```

Comment: Do you have a premium subscription to the API or are you just using the free tier? Requests are rate-limited by the API server; this isn't as much as an R limit as a twitter limit.

Comment: @MrFlick Got it, I'm just using free access. Is it possible to loop or something to get the list even with limited access?